# How to use splash:mouse_press in Scrapy-Splash

Tags: splash-js-render

I am trying yo click the display button on a website with no success and I really had no idea how to do it but I came across something that might work, `splash:mouse_press`.  Will that work with scrapy-splash and if so how do I implement it?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import NameItem

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "LoginSpider"
    start_urls = ["http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formcss='#existing_users form',
        formdata={'ex_usr_email': 'email@example.com', 'ex_usr_pass': 'password'},
        callback=self.after_login
        )
     def after_login(self, response):
        item = NameItem()
        item["Name"] = response.css("div.bl-result-title::text").get()
        return item
```

[image: HTML Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome here (:
No need to overcomplicate things.

All you need is `GET` request to `http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/search?search-type=name&name=game`
Well... of course you can vary params. But anyway you'll get all you want right in json format by this link.

It looks like even login isn't needed in fact.

Good luck.